# How do you use a "char" as a sentinel value in a while loop

Tags: c#

**My Instructions**:

> Implement a C# console application/program that makes use of a sentinel controlled while-loop structure to continuously prompt, read and store the test results entered by the user. The user will stop his/her input sequence by entering a ‘x’ character. You also need to make use of a switch selection structure (nested inside of the while loop).

e.g code to be used:

```
char stop = 'x';

Console.WriteLine("Enter result (x to stop): ");

results = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

while(results != stop)
{   
       Console.WriteLine("Enter result (x to stop): ");
       results = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

When I try to enter the 'x' as is, it does not work

Comment: No every `string` can be converted into single `char`, but every char can be represented as `string`: `while(results.Trim() != stop.ToString()) {...}`

Comment: `Convert.ToChar(Console.WriteLine());`?? Did you mean `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine())` instead?

Comment: sorry, I meant Convert.ToChar(Console.Readline());

Comment: but then you'd need to also press `Enter`

Comment: If you switch to a [do...while](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do) loop instead, then you'll only need ONE line getting input from the user that is INSIDE the loop.

Comment: I checked your code its working as soon as i press 'x' and enter loop exit. Only change i made is I declared  char datatype for results.

Answer (score 1):

you are using `Console.WriteLine`, but you should use `Console.ReadKey` and omit `Convert.ToChar` instead get the `KeyChar` property of the returned value.

so

```cs
while(results != stop)
{   
       Console.WriteLine("Enter result (x to stop): ");
       results = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
}
```

should work, I didn't test it

Answer (score 0):

You convert into wrong type: not every `string` can be converted into a *single* `char` (say, `"xenogg"`).
However, every char can be represented as a `string` with a help of `ToString()`:

```
    char stop = 'x';

    // Keep looping ...
    while (true) {
      // ...and asking user for input...
      Console.WriteLine("Enter result (x to stop): ");

      string results = Console.ReadLine();

      // ... until (s)he puts "x" 
      // put StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase if 'X' is exit as well as 'x'
      if (string.Equals(results.Trim(), x.ToString(), StringComparison.Ordinal))
        break;

      // results is not "x" 
      //TODO: add relevant code here
    }
```